# No tooltip on node hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am doing everything correctly according to my past experience: trying to append a tooltip to a circle, which worked for previous node link chart i did.

I created a div for the tooltip:

```
var div = d3.select("#vis").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);
```

and then called it with

```
var node = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9)
        div .html( ...
```

which works perfectly fine here: https://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/dRoXpp

However, **the problem starts here**: now I am trying to set up a similar tooltip but in a node-link force 
directed graph which you can also view here: https://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/BZdzZZ

I do the same process of setting up the tooltip, however when I try to call it with

```
var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)')
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {        
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.id) 
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");})
```

I have no error and I have no tooltip. I am not really sure why "mouseover" is not being registered at all, but other things that go after like "drag" are. What is the difference, and how should I fix this?

Comment: You have two ids on the div! `<div id="container" id="vis">...` ! So `d3.select("#vis").append("div"` does not work! Try `d3.select("#container").append("div")`

Comment: I see it now :D . Why does it often have to be something so minor. I am really quite embarrassed. Sorry :(

Comment: No worries! It's very easy to miss! :)